# Can Google Cloud Identity API return device software information

Tags: mobile, google-api, google-cloud-identity

The Admin SDK document: (https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/admin_directory_v1.mobiledevices.html#list) states:

list(customerId, maxResults=None, orderBy=None, pageToken=None, projection=None, query=None, sortOrder=None, x__xgafv=None)

Retrieves a paginated list of all user-owned mobile devices for an account. **To retrieve a list that includes company-owned devices, use the Cloud Identity [Devices API](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/concepts/overview-devices) instead.** This method times out after 60 minutes. For more information, see [Troubleshoot error codes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/troubleshoot-error-codes).

Is there a flag or parameter I can send in to the Cloud Identity API that will return the software information for the devices? The ADMIN SDK returns software inforamtion using the **mobiledevices**() call. If we have to use this Cloud Identity API for company-owned devices, we still need to pull the software for these devices as well as the device information itself.